# Adding an animation for an option menu

Tags: android, animation, google-chrome-app, android-optionsmenu

I have a custom toolbar with a overflow menu. I want to add some animation for opening this menu. Each item in the menu should fade in one after other with a total time of 200ms. How this can be achieved. I tried adding

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item1);
    item.getActionView().animate().alpha(1.0f).setStartDelay(50);
     item = menu.findItem(R.id.item2);
    item.getActionView().animate().alpha(1.0f);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.selection_mode_menu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item1);
    TextView v = new TextView(this);
    v.setText(item.getTitle());
    item.setActionView(v);

    item = menu.findItem(R.id.item2);
    v.setText(item.getTitle());
    item.setActionView(v);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

But this do not have any effect. How can this be done
The android chrome app has this menu animation